# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for with belongs_to. Why I can't set id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I use Rails 5.1.6 and have troubles with accepts_nested_attributes_for.

I have two models

```
class Material < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :rubric, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rubric
end

class Rubric < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :materials, dependent: :nullify
end
```

I try to set rubric id to new item by rubric_attributes.

```
describe 'create material' do
  it 'should set rubric: :id' do
    # prepare
    item = FactoryBot.build(:material)
    rubric = FactoryBot.create(:rubric)

    # action
    item.assign_attributes(
      rubric_attributes: {
        id: rubric.id
      }
    )

    # check
    expect(item.valid?).to eq(true)
    expect(item.save).to eq(true)
    expect(item.rubric_id).to eq(rubric.id)
  end
end
```

But I have an error:

```
 Failure/Error:
   item.assign_attributes(
     rubric_attributes: {
       id: rubric.id
     }
   )

 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
   Couldn't find Rubric with ID=1 for Material with ID=1
```

And I have the same error with updating a material.

Is it a predictable behavior of accepts_nested_attributes_for, and I can't use rubric_attributes for setting existed rubric id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods-label-One-to-many) say:

> For each hash that does not have an `id` key a new record will be instantiated, unless the hash also contains a _destroy key that evaluates to true.

It suggest that if you pass `id` in nested attributes, it's treated as an existing record that should be updated.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely don't need `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the first place.

If you want the user to be able to select records with a select you don't actually need to do anything besides create a select and whitelist the `material_id` attribute:

```
<%= form_for(@material) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :rubic_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :rubic_id, Rubic.all :id, :name %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The select will create an array in the params.

```
class MaterialsController
  # POST /materials
  def create
    @material = Material.new(material_params)
    if @material.save
      redirect_to @material
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def material_params
      params.require(:material)
            .permit(:foo, :bar, material_ids: [])
    end
end
```

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` is really intended for the case where you need to create / edit nested resources in the same request. The only reason you would use it here is:

1. The user should be able to create the material in the same form.
2. You have a join table with additional attributes (like quantity for example) which you want the user to be able to set.

You can still do 1. together with the select above, but you can't use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to set a simple `belongs_to` association. Nor would you want to either as its like using a rocket to beat in a nail.

Answer (score 2):

*Just leaving this in case somebody else may have a problem as I did, populating nested children records in a Rails backend via an API, but using hash_ids via friendly_id.*

**Came about this when trying to PATCH Rails records via an API.** First setup was to mirror the Rails way of sending the record values in nested form fashion. Meaning, I've purposefully built the params hash I was sending from the frontend over to a Rails backend like in a typical nested form transmission:

```
{ "children": {
      "0": {
            "name": "foo",
            "category_id": "1",
            "hash_id": "HDJPQT"
      }
}
```

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` needs `id` to PATCH records. Otherwise it is going to create a new record altogether. Which i did not want in my scenario. I was sending over `hash_id` and therefore creating new records unintentionally.

**Solution**

For the time being I am not replicating a nested form value hash anymore to send to the Rails backend anymore. Instead I am simply updating children records separately in a chained `fetch` query from the Javascript frontend.

*Note:*
*If you want to keep sending a mirrored nested form array of hashes, there could be a way to change the primary key of the database table to hash_id or UUID, depending on your needs. Have not yet tested this solution.*